# .kde/share/config permissions got messed up even after a reinstall

Tags: software-installation, permissions, software-center, uninstall

This Q is kind of a follow up from [this earlier Q](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654897/14-04-kate-editor-does-not-show-any-plugins-wrong-config-permission-even-after) where I had a strange issue with `kate` which didn't show any plug-ins. While I got it working now (by copying the `config` folder from one machine to another), I still don't quite understand why the permissions got messed up, and even more why that problem persists after a reinstall.

I used these commands to uninstalled `kate`:
`dpkg --get-selections | grep -i kate`

then for each found entry, I did these two:
`sudo apt-get autoremove kate`
`sudo apt-get --purge remove kate`

then I reinstall `kate` from Ubuntu Software Center.

- Are the above steps correct to reinstall a package in Ubuntu?
- Are there some missing steps that may have caused the package not being reinstalled in a clean state (that somehow affected the permissions in some `config` folders)?

Comment: The package manager won't touch any file in your home directory, so uninstalling or reinstalling won't affect permissions in your home directory.

Comment: Thanks @muru. So in general what should I do to make sure that I clean up everything of a package when I uninstall it? Including the config files (in this case `kate` stores some files in `./kde/share/config`).

Comment: In general, no sure way to tell. Firefox uses `.mozilla`, Thunderbird uses `.thunderbird`, Chrome `.{cache,config}/google-chrome`, yet others use `.local/share`. There's no general way to know.

Comment: Thanks. So Ubuntu install/uninstall/uninstall a package seems to remain a black art then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Package installation via `apt-get` and `dpkg` typically do not touch your user-specific preferences (settings) and documents. Programs that follow the [XDG Base Directory specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) will typically have their settings stored in the `~/.config/` folder. Some create subdirectories (such as `~/.config/vlc/`), others store a file directly in the directory (such as `~/.config/Texmakerrc`).

Other settings are typically found in so-called *dot-files* which are hidden files and directories stored in your home directory (such as `~/.mozilla/`).

Settings for KDE 4 can typically be found below `~/.kde/share/config/` or `~/.kde/share/appps/`. Another place to look for settings is `~/.local/share/`.

As a general hint, to find settings that have recently been changed, use the `find` program with the `-mmin -X` option  to look for files that were changed in the past `X` minutes. For example, find all files (`-type f`) in your home directory (`~`) that changed in the past ten minutes (`-mmin 10`) and print verbose information (`-ls`):

```
find ~ -type f -mmin -10 -ls
```